# Javascript file download losing extension on firefox

Tags: javascript, file, firefox, download

I have this function I use to download files in javascript.

```
function downloadURIXML(uri, name) {
     name = name.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9 \-\_]/, "");

     var link = document.createElement("a");
     link.download = name;
     link.href = uri;
     document.body.appendChild(link);
     link.click();
     setTimeout(function() {document.body.removeChild(link);}, 50);
}
```

Let's say I have a file named "test.docx" and I want to download it. I call

```
downloadURIXML(pathToFile, 'mynewfilename');
```

I would expect the file to download with filename: mynewfilename.docx

On Chrome it works as I expect but **on firefox the file extension is lost.** What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

```
link.download = name
```

Should provide a filename with extension i.e. `'mynewfilename.docx'`.
So You should rethink your function parameters as well as the `name.replace` since it will remove the `.`

You can see that even example at [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp) doesnt provide the extension in firefox browser.

Comment: I'm not getting it. In the examples you linked me I see this: <a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download="w3logo">. The download attribute doesn't contain the extension but when I download the image I get the file "wrlogo.jpg", so it works as I expected!

Comment: Did you check it on firefox? I get extensionless file downloaded

Comment: compare your chrome and firefox downloads @Jonny

Comment: Forgive me, I was conviced I was working on firefox... dah. Ok yes, it doesn't work on firefox. Thanks for the hint!